# Query Help - wmiobject win32_product filter items from text file

Tags: powershell, installed-applications

I've been working on a simple script to read the win32_product off a remote PC, which is working fine. However, I would like the query to ignore some common applications on my domain. I've been building a list of apps and their IdentifyingNumber and putting the IdentifyingNumber into a txt file. I load the text file into a variable with the script and I'm trying to figure out how to get the query to filter each item in the variable...so I have this::

```
$PC = Read-Host "What is target workstation..."
$logfile = "d:\$PC.txt"
$ignore = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("D:\INCOMING\AppListing\ignore.txt")
get-wmiobject -class win32_product -computer $PC | where {$_.IdentifyingNumber -notlike       $ignore} | Select Name, IdentifyingNumber | sort-object Name | export-csv $logfile -encoding "unicode"
```

However, this is not filtering at all, not even the first or last item from the txt file. I used write-host $ignore to verify it is loading the items...but I am at a lost as to how to make this work. Perhaps a foreach loop? I can't find anything about putting a foreach loop into a **where** filter though...

Thanks for the assistance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is like this:

```
aRandomId
anotherRandonId
...
```

with one id on each line and nothing else, then try this using `-notlike` with wildcards on the ends. Ex:

```
$PC = Read-Host "What is target workstation..."
$logfile = "d:\$PC.txt"
$ignore = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("D:\INCOMING\AppListing\ignore.txt")
get-wmiobject -class win32_product -computer $PC | where { $ignore -notlike "*$($_.identifyingnumber)*" } |
Select Name, IdentifyingNumber | sort-object Name | export-csv $logfile -encoding "unicode"
```

You could also read your file as an array using `ReadAllLines` like you would have had to do if you wanted to use a foreach-loop or `-notcontains`. Ex:

```
$PC = Read-Host "What is target workstation..."
$logfile = "d:\$PC.txt"
$ignore = [IO.File]::ReadAllLines("D:\INCOMING\AppListing\ignore.txt")
get-wmiobject -class win32_product -computer $PC | where { $ignore -notcontains $_.identifyingnumber } |
Select Name, IdentifyingNumber | sort-object Name | export-csv $logfile -encoding "unicode"
```

Comment: Yes, it's basically just IDs, one per line just as it would come from a query. So for instance {90120000-0115-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}  one per line. I tried using -notcontains already but unfortunately it still reports any of these items...

Comment: sry, forgot to switch the variables. try the updated answer. the array should be on the left of the `-notcontains`. see if that helps

Comment: Still grabbing all Installs in win32_product like that.

Comment: Oh, I see it. You're using `ReadAllText` and not `ReadAllLines` as I thought you did. See updated answer with two options to solve it.

Comment: So I can use ReadAllLines with this? I thought the setup of the txt file was different. Used ReadAllLines, and it works!   Tested with the solution you provided, and it also works. Thanks Graimer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$prods = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content $file) -DifferenceObject ((Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Computer $computer).IdentifyingNumber) -PassThru
```

Compare-Object is a great Cmdlet.